# Getting the Current Location Lat Long as 0.0 in Android google maps

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I want to latitude and longtitude at current location.
it run work on emulator but give lat/long 0.0 on mobile device.
my device is LG 4x hd.
src/.java file :

```
private TextView txt_lat,txt_lon,txt_gps;
private LocationManager lm;
double lat, lon;
protected LocationListener locatlist;
Location locat;
GpsStatus.Listener gpslist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt_lat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txt_lon= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    txt_gps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locat = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(locat != null) {
                lat = locat.getLatitude();
                lon = locat.getLongitude();
            }
            locatlist = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lon = location.getLongitude();
                    txt_lat.setText("lat : "+lat);
                    txt_lon.setText("lon : "+lon);
                }
            };
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locatlist);
            if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                txt_gps.setText("GPS is started");
            }
            else if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                txt_gps.setText("GPS is non-start");
            }
            txt_lat.setText("lat : "+lat);
            txt_lon.setText("lon : "+lon);
} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

mainfest permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

lat long is forever 0.0 on device but it work on emulator.
its a simple code and why its not working ?
Where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);-->may be here you get null value of location manager replace with this line  
lm = (LocationManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: it not work.I'm try replace then cannot run on emulator and device